# Lumia devices and windows phone developement

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8

Does the model of lumia devices make a difference in development, my app works on lumia 620 & 920 but crashes on lumia 520 & 625

Comment: Available RAM configurations? What services are required by your app

Comment: Maybe some memory isseues: [App memory limits for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Developing apps for lower-memory phones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh855081(v=vs.105).aspx)